# Executing a function as source in Django's Serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization

I have the following models:

```
class A(Model):
    pass

class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(A, related_name = 'b')
    b_field = CharField(max_length=64)
```

And I now want to serialize an A object, in which I want to have the first b object. I used to have this code:

```
class BSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'

class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    b = BSerializer(source='b.first')

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```

This used to work, but now my unit tests are failing:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `b_field` on serializer `BSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `method` instance.
Original exception text was: 'function' object has no attribute 'b_field'.
```

Obviously, `b.first` is a function, and that indeed has not such an attribute. I want the source field however to execute that function. I tried the following line:

```
    b = BSerializer(source='b.first')
```

But that gave met the following error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `b` on serializer `ASerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `A` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'first()'.
```

1. Has this behavior recently been changed?
2. How can I take the first b object inside a to serialize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specs around `source` has not changed, as you can read at the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):

> `source`: The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. May be a method that only takes a self argument, such as `URLField(source='get_absolute_url')`, or may use dotted notation to traverse attributes, such as `EmailField(source='user.email')`.

So, you should pass an attr or method name **of the class which instance is being serializing**, in your case `A`, or attr or method to traverse attributes (with dot notation) but always starting from an attr/method of the `A` class.

So, you can solve your problem this way:

```
class A(Model):
    def first_b(self):
        return self.b.first()


class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    b = BSerializer(source='first_b')

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__
```